# Intermittent problems deploying and debugging android app to phone

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I am currently investigating a problem I have where for some reason eclipse plugin/adb loses connection to my phone and gives me the message:

[2011-03-05 22:53:40 - projectOne] Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.testbed.input' on port 8633
[2011-03-05 23:04:02 - projectOne] ------------------------------
[2011-03-05 22:40:42 - projectOne] Android Launch!
[2011-03-05 22:40:42 - projectOne] adb is running normally.
[2011-03-05 22:40:42 - projectOne] Performing com.testbed.input.MainActivity activity launch
[2011-03-05 22:40:42 - projectOne] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.

And on the device monitor log I see this:

[2011-03-05 23:10:13 - Logcat]device (HT971L900496) request rejected: device offline
java.io.IOException: device (HT971L900496) request rejected: device offline

I cant figure out what it is, it just works flawless one day and next I get this.  I hope someone with a more expert knowledge of the tool chain can help as its really slowing me down so I am determined to get to the bottom of this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it happens but I have found a quick remedy - first kill any adb process.

Then start the adb again with the command 'adb start-server'.

This then allows me to connect to the phone again

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that intermittent "adb devices" problems can be put down to using the wrong USB port.
I think it has something to do with the power output of the various ports (i.e. not enough power).
I had intermittent problems with USB connection to Android Note II (Samsung Note 2 clone) for a week.
I didn't believe all the Google articles saying to use a different USB socket,
because I didn't think I had any others than the two on the front right of my Lenovo Thinkpad L420.
Guess what, after finally checking the back carefully, there it is, a single USB socket on the very end.
After plugging into that socket, "adb devices" always lists the device.
Hooray!
For the benefit of other (Ubuntu) users, I am showing my tips for getting "adb devices" to work.

> 1. Figure out how the device is recognized by Ubuntu Linux.
>      Plug in the device, do "lsusb" then use the first hex number of the device ("0bb4" here)
>      as the "idVendor" attribute in a file called, "/etc/udev/rules.d/99-android.rules",
>      with the following, one-line contents:
>          SUBSYSTEM=="usb",ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4",MODE="0666",GROUP="plugdev" 
>      ** Do not put spaces after the commas in this line.
>      Then, "sudo service udev restart".
> 2. Don't forget to add yourself to the "plugdev" group: "sudo usermod -aG plugdev".
> 3. Execute: adb kill-server; adb start-server; adb devices.
>      The adb server listens on port 127.0.0.1:5037 (netstat -anp|grep LISTEN).
>      So if any adb command is hanging, check that you can "ping 127.0.0.1".
>      If localhost ping fails, check firewalls and also check "sudo iptables-save",
>      looking for a missing "allow" rule for localhost ("lo").
>      Also, "ifconfig -a" will expose whether localhost interface is up (Google "ifup").

I hope someone else finds this information useful.

Answer (score 0):

Another nugget of information for others that I found:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/5fb922c2166eab68

I had the usb plugged into the front of my computer and I was experiancing problems - after pluging it at the back direct to the usb controller and not a hub it has become much more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Here is my solution: you have to connect the USB cable from your PC to your phone while pressing the power button of you phone.